# VC++ 2010 ignoring breakpoints

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging, breakpoints

Last Friday before I went home for the weekend, breakpoints in my code were working fine.  Today, they are not working fine.

Since last Friday, I

- Rebooted my computer
- Downloaded new source code from TFS code repository
- Cleaned and built the entire solution for Release mode
- Cleaned and built the entire solution for Debug mode
- Added/moved a few lines from two source modules
- Cleaned and rebuilt just the project that I am working on.
- Debugged the solution with no parameters -- breakpoints worked correctly
- Debugged the solution with parameters to run to just my part of the code -- breakpoints do not work, but from the output from the program, it is clear that that portion of the code had run.
- I do not recall anything else that I might have done to cause this behavior.

I have seen this before, but I do not recall how I corrected the situation.

This is a Unit Test project, so it is never built in Release mode.  I have checked the date/time stamp on the file to ensure that the executable that I just built is the one I am about to run.

If I set a breakpoint at the entrypoint of the executable, the debugger stops there, but not at any other breakpoint that I've set.

This is completely Native code, so please don't bother with .NET options that do not apply and that I cannot access anyway because I'm coding in C++.

What can cause the IDE to suddenly turn off debugging like this?

Thanks in advance,

Richard Johnson

Comment: Last time this happened to me, I had created a new solution configuration (apart from Debug and Release) and forgot to check to enable debug for that config.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I almost hate to mention - are you sure your solution built completely?  If not, your breakpoints would be out of sync with the binary and VS would disable them.  You'd see that with a yellow overlay on the breakpoint icon.  Assuming a good build, you might have to delete your NCB (Intellisense db) file, if it's become corrupt.  Doing a clean rebuild won't do this.  If that doesn't help, let us know what your exact symptoms are - does the breakpoint "light up" in the IDE, but just not fire?  Or does the IDE refuse to turn the breakpoint on altogether?